# SpringSecurity Login not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

i went through some tutorials and build myself a Spring Security Login.
But whenever I login I get the following errors from the log:

```
2015-08-12 21:39:21 DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource:142 - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sailplanner]
2015-08-12 21:39:21 TRACE StatementCreatorUtils:225 - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [abc@gmail.com], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
2015-08-12 21:39:21 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2015-08-12 21:39:21 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:693 - Executing prepared SQL query
2015-08-12 21:39:21 DEBUG JdbcTemplate:627 - Executing prepared SQL statement [select u.email, ur.role from user_roles ur left outer join users u on (ur.user_id = u.id) where u.email=?]
2015-08-12 21:39:21 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:110 - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource
2015-08-12 21:39:21 DEBUG DriverManagerDataSource:142 - Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sailplanner]
2015-08-12 21:39:21 TRACE StatementCreatorUtils:225 - Setting SQL statement parameter value: column index 1, parameter value [1], value class [java.lang.String], SQL type unknown
2015-08-12 21:39:21 DEBUG DataSourceUtils:327 - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2015-08-12 21:39:21 DEBUG JdbcUserDetailsManager:200 - User 'abc@gmail.com' has no authorities and will be treated as 'not found'
2015-08-12 21:39:21 DEBUG DaoAuthenticationProvider:147 - User 'abc@gmail.com' not found
```

I get the result below, when starting the following SQL request:

```
select u.email, ur.role from user_roles ur left outer join users u on (ur.user_id = u.id) where u.email="abc@gmail.com"
```

Result:

```
abc@gmail.com   ROLE_USER
abc@gmail.com   ROLE_ADMIN
```

I have the following spring-secuity.xml setup:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">

        <intercept-url pattern="/inside**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/welcome" 
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"  
            username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />

        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout"  />

        <csrf/>
    </http>

    <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
    <authentication-manager>
      <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
          users-by-username-query=
            "select id, first_name, last_name, weight, email, password from users where email=?" 
          authorities-by-username-query=
            "select u.email, ur.role from user_roles ur left outer join users u on (ur.user_id = u.id) where u.email=?"
            />
      </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The users-by-username-query needs to just select username, password and enabled.

The authorities-by-username-query doesn't need the join, the authorities are fetched with a second select.

So something like (assuming you're using email for username?)

```
<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
      users-by-username-query=
        "select email, password, true from users where email=?" 

      authorities-by-username-query=
        "select u.email, ur.role from user_roles ur left outer join users u on (ur.user_id = u.id) where u.email=?"
        />
```

Comment: You are my hero... ! THANK YOU.
But my `authorities-by-username-query` was correct, because I am using numeric ids and not other ids. So there is no email in the user_roles table. Please see my suggestion....

Answer (score 0):

It is using liferay right? If you are using, try with the username not with the email, i think that could solve your problem :)

Comment: I am not using liferay - that I know of.
And having a username is no option! I have no username in my database and no username in my setup. I don't want a username!

Comment: The problem that I see is that you'r not being able to get the roles of the user
2015-08-12 21:39:21 DEBUG JdbcUserDetailsManager:200 - User 'abc@gmail.com' has no authorities and will be treated as 'not found'

Comment: Yes thats what I recon. But trying the same statement in mysql worked. And the database connection seems to be fine, according to logs. If I alter the statement in Spring to something else, I get another error, about wrong statement.
I am unable to find the reason for `no authorities`....